# How to correctly subscribe the pixel value over the pixmap in the QGraphicsScene (as it is in OpenCV namedWindow)?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I am trying to implement the same functionality in my widget as it is in cv:: namedWindow.

The goal is to enable zooming and to make the overlay with the grid and the values of pixel's colors directly over the original pixmap. Here is the example: сv picture zoomed:

[image: сv picture zoomed]

I inherited the QGraphicsView widget, added to QGraphicsScene the QGraphicsPixmapItem and reimplemented the QWheelEvent so that zooming in and out works correctly now. The problem starts with creating an overlay.

Instead of creating a pack of QGraphicsLineItems and adding them to the scene in order to make the grid, I inherit the QGraphicsRectItem and draw the whole grid on it.

```
void QGraphicsOverlayItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QPen pen(Qt::black);
    pen.setWidthF(0.02);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setBrush(Qt::BrushStyle::NoBrush);

    QVector<QLineF> crossLines = createCrossLines();
    painter->drawLines(crossLines);
}
```

This works very fast. But when I try to drawText with the QPainter and set the QFont:: pointSizeF() as small as possible, it works incorrectly (symbols change their size from small to huge during zooming or even disappear at all). Nevertheless, the best result that I get this way is the following:
the QPainter's drawText() result:
[image: the QPainter's drawText() result]

```
    QFont font(painter->font());
    font.setPointSizeF(0.1);
    font.setLetterSpacing(QFont::SpacingType::AbsoluteSpacing,0.01);
    painter->setFont(font);
    painter->drawText(432,195,"123");
```

The easiest way is to add to scene a lot of QGraphicsTextItems and scale them to correct size, but it is too slow.

So the question is how can I subscribe the pixel's color value in the QGraphicsScene directly over the QPixmapItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally watched through the openCV source code and found what I looked for.

The answer for me was the QTransform matrix. OpenCV developers show the image not by using the scene in the QGraphicsView, but actually painting the image directly on the viewport in the paintEvent.
The QTransform matrix is stored in the class and is passed to QPainter in the beginning of the paintEvent.

```
void DefaultViewPort::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(viewport());
    painter.setWorldTransform(param_matrixWorld);
    painter.drawImage(QRect(0,0,viewport()->width(),viewport()->height()),image2Draw,QRect(0,0,image2Draw.width(),image2Draw.height()));
```

If you know the ratio of the image's size to the widget's size, and you also know the scale of QTransform matrix used to paint the image, it is easy to calculate how much area does the single source pixel take on the screen:

```
qreal ratioX = width() /  float(image2Draw.width());
qreal ratioY = height() / float(image2Draw.height());
double pixel_width  = qtransform_matrixWorld.m11()*ratioX;
double pixel_height = qtransform_matrixWorld.m11()*ratioY;
```

If we know the pixel_height, we can just set the QFont::pixelSize like this:

```
QFont font = painter->font();
font.setPixelSize(pixel_height/5);
painter->setFont(font);
```